# a problem on sum of two different sets and their properties

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Define
$A + B = \{x + y \mid x \in A; y \in B\}$
Pick out the true statements:
a. if $A$  and $B$ are closed sets, then $A + B$ is a closed set;
b. if $A$  is an open set and if $B$ is a closed set, then $A + B$ is an open set;
c. if $A$  and $B$ are compact sets, then so is $A + B$.

---

(a) is not true and (c)  is true.
for (b) I am little confused. it looks like true intuitively but I have no general proof.

Comment: This posting had "A+B" inside TeX, then "={" outside TeX, then "x+y" inside TeX, etc.  I changed it to have "A+B=\{x+y\mid x\in A; y\in B\}" all inside TeX.  That is standard usage.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For (b), let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$; you want to find an open neighborhood of $a+b$ contained in $A+B$. Since $A$ is open there is an $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subseteq A$, where $B(a,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $a$. Clearly $$B(a,r)+b=\{x+b:x\in B(a,r)\}\subseteq A+B\;,$$ so you’re done if you can show that $B(a,r)+b$ is an open neighborhood of $a+b$. It’s just the open ball $B(a,r)$ translated by the vector $b$, so you’d expect it to be the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $a+b$, and the natural thing to do is to try to show that $B(a,r)+b=B(a+b,r)$. You need only the fact that in $\Bbb R^n$ the usual Euclidean distance is *translation invariant*: for any $x,y,z\in\Bbb R^n$,

$$\|(x+z)-(y+z)\|=\|x-y\|\;.$$